# What are some really good algebra tutorials?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

What are some really good algebra tutorials?

I am OK with exponents and logarithms. However, I would like to learn algebra, with quadratic equations and polynomials.

I've found out about Khan Academy. That gets boring at some times. There is also thenewboston and MathPlanet.

I don't want books, I just want free, online resources that are good for a beginner.

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about your aim? Is it for high school, or university?  Do you like math and want to see more, or is you focus more on passing the next exam?  Maybe something like this: [edX: College Algebra Problem Solving](https://www.edx.org/course/college-algebra-problem-solving-asux-mat117x)?  PS: My advice would be: Do math with someone together, a classmate or a friend with similar aim. Doing it together is a good motivation!

Comment: I would love to learn more maths. I'm self-learning right now.

Comment: I guess I can't really help you. The questions is too uncertain and I know little about high school education. I would take a look at some linear algebra, i.e. stuff like this: [Gilbert Strang: Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c). (This guy is also a great teacher!) You can find linear algebra problems for example here [Lemma](https://www.lem.ma/books/Ai_Km5W5WPfsPZqqV2XWGg/problems)
 In linear algebra you learn quite a lot of general ideas, for example how to solve linear systems. But also it maybe shows a few abstract structures which are interesting.

Comment: What I need are some resources (a list of them) to learn Algebra. Not books, but things online.

Comment: Your aversion to books may be wrong-headed.  (I said "may.")  If you're trying to learn math by watching videos, it's probably not going to work.  You need to work problems with pencil and paper.  Watching videos is no more productive for math than it would be for learning piano.  Books have large lists of problems.  The online stuff, not so much.

Comment: A PDF would be nice. Thank you anyway!

Comment: [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) I have personally used it - it's one of the best online and offline resources out there.

Comment: A small bit of advice, enjoy maths _actively_ instead of passively. It does not matter whether it is offline or online but you must experience maths yourself. While making the choice of offline vs online keep in mind these few things - (i) First and foremost which method of learning do _you_ like more? (ii) offline resources are more extensive than online ones (although online ones are catching up fast) (iii) Due to various reasons - the primary means of testing math knowledge is unfortunately exams which are usually offline. Familiarity with pen and paper tests may help you score more.